# Spring Boot AMQP retry on exception behavior

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, retry-logic

I am using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:3.0.5` to consume messages from RabbitMQ queue.

I set up a DLQ for my queue, so when my listener throws `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` the message is successfully moved to DLQ. Also, if the message is not a valid JSON and `MessageConversionException` is thrown it also goes to DLQ. This is OK.

When some other runtime exception is thrown from the listener it gets infinitely retried without any intervals spamming the logs with stacktraces. This is NOT OK. What I would like to have is some reasonable exponential retry strategy.

I've tried to add this magic config in `application.yml`:

```
spring:  
  rabbitmq:
    listener:
      simple:
        retry:
          enabled: true
          initial-interval: 3s
          max-attempts: 5
          max-interval: 10s
          multiplier: 2
```

It works: now the exceptions thrown from the listener are retried several times with an increasing interval and then moved to DLQ. This is OK.

The issue is that now ALL the exceptions are being retried in the same way. Including `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` and `MessageConversionException`.

Is there a way to keep the original behavior (no retries, immediate routing to DLQ) for `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` and `MessageConversionException` and at the same time apply the exponential back-off retry strategy for all other exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging and digging into Spring code I've found out that the way to customise the default retry behavior is to define a `RabbitRetryTemplateCustomizer` instance. Then you can set your own instance of `SimpleRetryPolicy` to the preconfigured `RetryTemplate`.

```java
  @Bean
  public RabbitRetryTemplateCustomizer rabbitRetryTemplateCustomizer(
      @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts}") int maxAttempts) {
    Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> exceptionMap = Map.of(
        AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException.class, false,
        MessageConversionException.class, false,
        org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException.class, false,
        MethodArgumentResolutionException.class, false,
        NoSuchMethodException.class, false,
        ClassCastException.class, false
    );
    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(maxAttempts, exceptionMap, true, true);
    return (target, retryTemplate) -> retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
  }
```

The downside is that:

1. I had to manually access `spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts` property because it is mandatory to create a `SimpleRetryPolicy`
2. I had to copy-paste the list of non-retriable exceptions from `ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.DefaultExceptionStrategy.isCauseFatal` method.

Would have been nice if the framework provided an easier way to specify which exceptions are subject to retry. Like listing the list of exception classes to exclude in `application.yml` together with the rest of retry properties.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it can be configured through config, but if you create your beans programmatically you should be able to set `retry policy` and `backoff policy` to your `RetryTemplate`. Backoff policy is what you already defined in config, but for retry policy you can use `ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy` which allows you to set `exceptionClassifier` and based on that you can have different policy for different exceptions. For that you can pass your own implementation of `Classifier`, implementing `classify` method which returns policy.

Quick and dirty way of configuring it.

```
@Bean
fun rabbitTemplate(connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory): RabbitTemplate {
    val rabbitTemplate = RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory)
    val retryTemplate = RetryTemplate()

    val classifier = object : Classifier<Throwable, RetryPolicy> {
        val listOfNonRetryableExceptions = emptyList<Throwable>()
        override fun classify(classifiable: Throwable?): RetryPolicy {
            return if (listOfNonRetryableExceptions.contains(classifiable)) {
                NeverRetryPolicy()
            } else {
                SimpleRetryPolicy()
            }
        }
    }
    val exceptionClassifierRetryPolicy = ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy()
    exceptionClassifierRetryPolicy.setExceptionClassifier(classifier)

    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(exceptionClassifierRetryPolicy)
    rabbitTemplate.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate)
    return rabbitTemplate
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And how should I use that RetryTemplate? Just defining it as a bean doesn't work. I also tried to define as a bean RabbitTemplate and SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory and set RetryTemplate to them but nothing worked. Retries don't happen at all.

Comment: Sorry, I missed one line, added it now. You can set it to RabbitTemplate with `setRetryTemplate`